# Functions that get infinitely "tight"

Tags: real-analysis

I was thinking recently about what happens to certain periodic functions as their period decreases. Take as an example, the following function
$$
\varphi(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\{x\}, & 0 \le \{x\} \le \frac{1}{2}\\
1 - \{x\}, & \frac{1}{2} \le \{x\} \le 1
\end{cases}
$$
where $\{x\} = x - \lfloor{x}\rfloor$. $\varphi(x)$ looks somewhat like a triangle wave. Now consider $\varphi(mx)$ for some real number $m$. $\varphi(mx)$ is similar to $\varphi(x)$, but the former's period is $\frac{1}{m}$ whereas the latter's is $1$. So, how would you describe the function
$$
\phi(x) = \lim_{m\to\infty}{\varphi(mx)}?
$$
The period gets closer to $0$, so is $\phi(x)$ simply defined nowhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit in your definition of $\phi$ doesn't exist other than for $x=0$. So $\phi$ is not defined anywhere except at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are interested in the following result (sometimes known as the *generalized Riemann-Lebesgue lemma*): if $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ is $1$-periodic, then for  any interval $[a,b]$ one has that 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^bf(nx)\phi(x)\, dx = \int_0^1 f(y)\,dy\int_a^b\phi(x)\, dx, \quad \forall \phi\in C(a, b),$$
that is, the sequence $f(nx)$ converges to the constant $\int_0^1 f(y)\, dy$ in a weak sense. When $f(x)=e^{ix}$ one recovers the standard Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.